# A version of the Riemann existence theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, sheaf-theory, riemann-surfaces

While I was reading [these notes](https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/david_loeffler/teaching/modularcurves/lecture_notes.pdf), I've found the following version of the so called "Riemann existence theorem".

[image]

Do you know any reference for the proof of **this statement**?

**Remark:** In the algebraic setting, the result is very easy to show because the sheaf of meromorphic functions $\mathscr M_X$ is replaced by the locally constant sheaf given by the function field $K(X)$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423191/why-do-global-rational-sections-of-line-bundles-exist)). I think that the key word here is "GAGA"but I don't know exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Riemann Roch, for example, you can find an embedding of $X$ in some $\Bbb P^N$. Similarly, for sufficiently large $k\in\Bbb N$, the line bundle (invertible sheaf) $\mathscr F\otimes \mathscr O(k)$ has a nontrivial global holomorphic section $s$. Letting $\sigma$ be a nontrivial section of $\mathscr O(k)$, i.e., a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$ (restricted to $X$), $s/\sigma$ is a global meromorphic section of $\mathscr F$.